# Cloudinary SDK in Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6, cloudinary

Is there a way to use Obj-C SDK in a Swift file?
I've tried to add cloudinary SDK to my project. I found a way to add libcloudinary.a to my project Frameworks but its not working.

**UPDATE**: Cloudinary have just published new SDKs written in the Swift language: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios (Swift 3 and Swift 2.3 on separate brunches)

Comment: See guidance here: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios/issues/20

Comment: New Swift support is now available on Cloudinary - https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

First, you will need to get your xcode project setup as per their instructions found [here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios). You will then need to create a bridging header file as defined in the [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html).

example

```
#ifndef Fun_Bridging_Header_h
#define Fun_Bridging_Header_h

#import "Cloudinary.h"

#endif
```

Unfortunately their objective-c API is not fully interoperable with Swift, namely their upload API (CLUploader).

What I've had to do to make it work was to create a factory class in objective-c for it

The interface (CloudinaryFactory.h)

```
#ifndef Fun_Wrappy_h
#define Fun_Wrappy_h
#import "Cloudinary.h"

@interface CloudinaryFactory : NSObject  
+ (CLUploader*)create:(CLCloudinary*)cloudinary delegate:(id <CLUploaderDelegate> )delegate;
@end

#endif
```

The implementation (CloudinaryFactory.m):

```
#import "CloudinaryFactory.h"

@implementation CloudinaryFactory  

+ (CLUploader*)create:(CLCloudinary*)cloudinary delegate:(id <CLUploaderDelegate> )delegate
{
    return [[CLUploader alloc] init:cloudinary delegate:delegate];
}

@end
```

And the updated bridging file

```
#ifndef Fun_Bridging_Header_h
#define Fun_Bridging_Header_h

#import "CloudinaryFactory.h"

#endif
```

Now, to use it:

```
 var image:UIImage? //todo: i'm assuming you would set this somewhere
 @IBAction func uploadGarment(sender: AnyObject) {
    let clouder = CLCloudinary(url: "cloudinary://your:cloudinary@url")

    let forUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as NSData
    let uploader = CloudinaryFactory.create(clouder, delegate: self)

    uploader.upload(forUpload, options: ["public_id":"testo"])   

}
```

I hope it helps! for more, here's the related [blog post](http://47ron.in/blog/2015/01/08/uploading-pictures-to-cloudinary-using-swift.html)

Comment: this is what we ended up doing as well, would love to see swift support from cloudinary soon

Comment: In the third paragraph of the Setup section in that github link, what are the steps for swift? I can't find any `Other Linker Flags` setting

Answer (score 6):

These are working for me:

1. Create or append to the Podfile file: `pod "Cloudinary"`
2. Run `pod install` and then open the workspace file, not the project.
3. Add an Obj-C file to your project (http://cl.ly/image/272V1Z2Q3g0e) and when asked say yes to adding an Objective-C bridging header
4. In this file add `#import "Cloudinary/Cloudinary.h"`
5. You may now use the Cloudinary API. Here is some code to upload:

   ```
   let cloudinary_url = "cloudinary://API_KEY:API_SECRET@CLOUD_NAME"
   var uploader:CLUploader = CLUploader(cloudinary, delegate: self)
   uploader.upload(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(new_image, 0.8), options: ["format":"jpg"], withCompletion: { ([NSObject : AnyObject]!, errorResult:String!, code:Int, context:AnyObject!) -> Void in

   }, andProgress: { (p1:Int, p2:Int, p3:Int, p4:AnyObject!) -> Void in

   })
   ```

Comment: hi, I'm trying to use wloudinary in my swift app, i used a header file but Im getting this error:  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLCloudinary", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.CLCloudinary in CloudinaryController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the iOS sample code here:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios#upload.

In addition, here's a code reference:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios/blob/master/CloudinaryTests/UploaderTests.m

Also, you can use Cloudinary's unsigned upload. Here's some more information including an iOS example: http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud#api_example_2

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any swift samples?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently no, only the objective C sample as mentioned in the blog.

Answer (score 1):

Create **Bridging Header File** in your project. After that import **.h** file into bridging-header file.

See here :
**1 step:** xyz-Bridging-header.h

Import Cloudinary.h file into Bridging-header file

```
#import "Cloudinary.h"
```

2 Step : ViewController.swift

```
Class viewController : UIViewController {
      cloudinary: CLCloudinary = CLCloudinary()
      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Cloudinary Setup
            cloudinary.config().setValue("xxxxxxxx", forKey: "cloud_name")
            cloudinary.config().setValue("xxxxxxxx", forKey: "api_key")
            cloudinary.config().setValue("xxxxxxxx", forKey: "api_secret")
      }
}
```

Your **Cloudinary** setup is done. now you can able to use.